# OS X can't unmount disk

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

My 1TB LaCie Rugged THB decided it was a good idea to stop working all of a sudden.
If I open it in disk util I sometimes see an actual name of a partition, but most likely it's not the real name.

In Terminal I tried:

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            140.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                110.1 GB   disk0s4
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                  Apple_HFS                         150.1 GB   disk1s1
   2:                 DOS_FAT_32 BAK_WIN                 150.0 GB   disk1s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS                         100.0 GB   disk1s3
   4:                 DOS_FAT_32                         120.0 GB   disk1s5
   5:                 DOS_FAT_32                         480.1 GB   disk1s6
```

And then to unmount this:

```
$sudo diskutil unmountDisk force disk1
```

gave this: Forced unmount of disk1 failed: at least one volume could not be unmounted
Than for each disk:

```
$sudo diskutil unmount force disk1sn
```

Always: disk1sn was already unmounted

Because I wasn't able to do anything with my external HDD I made a desperate attempt to erase everything on it, including unbackuped files, cause this used to be the backup plan. This was the try:

```
$ sudo diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ DISK_VOLUME disk1
Started erase on disk1
Unmounting disk
Error: -69888: Couldn't unmount disk
```

But it didn't work as well. If you have any idea to get the HDD working or even safe the files, I would be really grateful.

Almost forgot about this from Disk Utility:
Disk Utility can’t repair this disk. Back up as many of your files as possible, reformat the disk, and restore your backed-up files.

Comment: Just to be clear - you don't need any files from this drive, just that you want it to get erased and put back into service?

Comment: I'd like to have the files, but if there is no other way, I'd be grateful to be even able to use it again. But would mean the loss of many fotos :-/

Comment: This answer helped me! https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9217/resource-busy-error-when-using-dd-to-copy-disk-img-to-sd-card

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For me, none of the solutions were working: sudo unmount, sudo unmountDisk, unmountDisk force, etc., with /dev/disk4, /dev/disk4s1, /dev/disk4s2, and so on. All failed. The last thing I tried - eraseDisk - gave me the same error: Error: -69888: Couldn't unmount disk

Then I decided to see if there were any processes in my way, so I ran `sudo lsof|grep disk4` and found a process working on one of my partitions. I killed the process id and suddenly the disk mounted again! Success!

Comment: Well the disk hasn't worked until today. But I kept it, lets see what I can do :)

Comment: Good luck, hope it works!

Comment: Although I believe in your answear (also found it in other blogs) my system won't recognize the drive anymore. But thank you anyway :)

Comment: @PeterSchmucki can you see the disk at all when you run `diskutil`? (I have more experience fixing bad drives on windows, so that would be my next solution: find a windows machine and delve into it there.)

Comment: Wasn't able to see it `diskutil` last time, however I sometimes see the drive on Windows 7. I have my main disk partitioned, I could boot from Windows. My VM of Linux on the other hand never saw the disk, probably a configurtation issue, don't really sure about it though

Comment: For me, macOS was helpfully trying to fsck the disk. The offending process was 'fsck_hfs' with '/dev/rdisk...' open.

Comment: This worked and I can now erase the drive, but if you want your data, if may be worth waiting until `fsck_hfs` completes. After a long time the drive suddenly connected and I could back up a few things, then I erased it via `diskutil`

Comment: The *only* thing that worked for me was running (in Terminal, NOT iterm): `diskutil zeroDisk disk#`

Answer (score 7):

The same thing happened to me because I was in the same directory as the USB drive.

I went back into my home directory (cd ~) and ran the command again and it worked.

Comment: this worked because I was trying to unmount the disk while I was in the disk (dooh). I just used ``cd ..`` to go up a level which moved me outside of the disk I was trying to unmount.

Comment: +1 Unbelievable, I've tried so much until cd ~ solved the problem.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I found I got this problem when I was using iTerm instead of terminal, if the other fixes don't help try changing to terminal if you're using something else

Answer (score 2):

I confirm that using *Terminal* instead of *iTerm2* surprisingly made the command `diskutil unmount` and `diskutil mount` work!

Comment: Strange this just worked for me too, never would have thought to try it.

Comment: add iTerm to SIP if this happens

Answer (score 0):

All of these methods above used to work on my machine. It seems that after a while it won't work anymore.
For some reason, this problem begins to happen whenever the drive is removed unsafely. For instance, my macbook doesn't have a battery, so, if the electricity of my house fails or if the power cord is unplugged, when I reboot my computer, the drive won't work.

The only way I found to work every time is to launch a virtual machine, with a Linux distro or Windows, on the same computer isn't mounting and force the drive to mount on it. [1] You can click on devices, usb 2.0 (or 3.0) and look for the device. As soon as it mounts, you remove it safely, shutdown the virtual machine, or uncheck the device, reversing the step [1].

If it doesn't automatically shows up on your Mac, you can unplug it and plug it again.

Ps.: This method was done using a Virtual Box VM, but it'll probably work using Parallels, VMWare or even a Live CD (usb) Linux Distro.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the Apple help info, when erroring during the eject, logging out from the session (**Apple logo** > **Logout**) and coming back was enough to eject it.