# External Disk not recognized, can't unmount, cannot erase

Tags: hard-drive, diskutil

I have an external drive which is only recognised running diskutil list in Terminal, not in the GUI version or Finder:

```
/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk1
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
2:                  Apple_HFS Backup                  250.0 GB   disk1s2
3:       Microsoft Basic Data XHDD                    249.6 GB   disk1s3
```

**I have tried the following:**

```
diskutil verifyDisk disk1
```

*Problems were found with the partition map which might prevent booting
Error: -69808: Some information was unavailable during an internal lookup*

```
diskutil verifyVolume disk1sn
diskutil repairVolume disk1sn
```

*Error starting file system verification for (bad disk ref): Disk object invalid or unable to serialize (-69810)*

```
diskutil repairDisk disk1
```

*Problems were encountered during repair of the partition map
Error: -69808: Some information was unavailable during an internal lookup*

```
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ Untitled disk1
```

*Error: -69888: Couldn't unmount disk*
or:
*Error: -69877: Couldn't open device*

For the first error I did subsequently:

```
diskutil unmountDisk force disk1
```

Which most of the time was sucessful. If not, I even tried to find processes that interfered with the drive (found here: [stackex/os-x-cant-unmount-disk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209992/os-x-cant-unmount-disk))

```
sudo lsof|grep disk1
```

Which did not find any processes.

In fact, now i can't even get to the unmountable part and alwas get the:

*Error: -69877: Couldn't open device*

Is this thing really done or is there more to do here?

Comment: If it is not in the GUI or finder, then it is not mounted - which is why you can't unmount it and that function is greyed out...

Comment: Good to know, but mounting it just says that is not possible. And still: The erase verb wants me to have it unmounted anyway but still does not work.

Answer (score 2):

When the command line cannot erase the disk, it’s time to reseat and replace all cables or take that drive to another Mac to eliminate a hardware failure.

You are using the correct erase syntax so this is major macOS side failure (unlikely but certainly possible) or hardware failure (likely).

Comment: Okay, I will try, maybe also with a Windows machine. Will report back.

Answer (score 0):

I find when I run in to these problems I use Linux to reformat the disk because sometimes the disk is so messed up even windows won’t be able to do anything.

Comment: What would you do in Linux? I mean, do I not effectively invoke the same commands when using diskutil in the OSX command line?

Comment: @lthz yes but sometimes there are restrictions in OS X and in Linux there is a better GUI disk utility

Comment: I've tried other OS for some edge cases - sometimes an oddball driver or flakey cable likes one chipset or timing of commands over the other. In theory - it shouldn't matter. In practice, sometimes it does.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to run diskutil erase as superuser

```
sudo diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ DISKNAME disk1
```

In order to access the volume. this might have to to with the EFI boot partition still in place on the disk.

At least this worked after having erased anything but the EFI on a windows machine.